# Why is many2many field not getting saved in django?

Tags: python, django, view, m2m

`user,package,travellers` fields are getting saved for the `CustomizeRequest` model except for the `destinations` field(many2manyfield).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

**models.py**

```
class CustomizeRequest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    package = models.CharField(max_length   =20,null=True,blank=True)
    travellers = models.CharField(max_length=2)     
    destinations = models.ManyToManyField(DestinationChoices)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.travellers
```

**views.py**

```
def packageDetails(request,slug):
    package = Package.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = CustomizeRequestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            customize_request = form.save(commit=False)
            customize_request.user = request.user           
            customize_request.package = package
            customize_request.save()
            form.save_m2m()
        else:
            print("errorerrorerrorerrorerror")
    else:       
        print("notPostData")

    crform = CustomizeRequestForm()
    elements = CustomizeRequest.objects.filter(user=request.user,package=package)
    destinations = DestinationChoices.objects.all()
    context = {'package': package,'crform':crform,'elements':elements,'destinations':destinations }
    return render(request,'tour/packageDetails.html',context)
```

**forms.py**

```
nTravellerCHOICES = (('1', '1',), ('2', '2',), ('3', '3',), ('4', '4',), ('5', '5',), ('6', '6',), ('7', '>6',))

class CustomizeRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    travellers = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.RadioSelect,choices = nTravellerCHOICES)
    destinations = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False,queryset=DestinationChoices.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = CustomizeRequest
        fields = ("travellers","destinations",)
```

Not pasting the template code, as i am pretty sure the problem lies in the model or view code since its a saving issue

Comment: Are you sure `M2M` not saving.? Your code just fine & It'will save `M2M` for you.

Comment: Yup,not saving. that is what even me not understanding. code seems fine. but something wierd is happening. wish some1 cud shed some light

Comment: So I don't always recommend this, but if you stick a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in there before your `save_m2m()` call, and then step into that save_m2m is anything weird going on?